# maps and smaps , percentage in RAM

Tags: linux

How to find percentage in RAM used by a process with /proc/[PID]/maps or /proc/[PID]/smaps   like this :
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the htop man: https://linux.die.net/man/1/htop

You'll find what you need :).

Best regards.

Comment: thanks! But is it possible with only maps or smaps ?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with directly.

Comment: But you can do it with the information in /proc/meminfo, you can get there the "MemTotal" & the "MemFree" of your system, it's up to you to make the percentage between its 2 values.